# Synchronize Local db to Azure

Tags: c#, sql, azure, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Hi im making a local todo Windows Phone 8 app with a local database

```
public static string DBConnectionString = "Data Source=isostore:/todo.sdf";
```

Now I need a method to synchronize the local database items with Azure db.

I'm not sure how to proceed to not add duplicate items to Azure database.

```
public void synchronizeLocalToAzure()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < AllTodoItems.Count; i++)
        {
            azureItems.Add(AllTodoItems[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that, but you must create a TestFunction in the insert method of Azure.

This will help you to not add a duplicate items.

```
function test(item) {
var tab= tables.getTable('YOUR_TABLE');
tab.read({
    success: function(x) {
        x.forEach(function(Item_in_data_base) {
           if ( Item_in_data_base.Id==item.Id)
           {
               return true;
           }
        });
    } return false;
});
}
```

then update your insert function:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
    if(!test) {
              request.execute({
              success: function() {
              request.respond();
               }
               });
}}
```

I hope this will help you.